# Find the sequence

Tags: code-golf, math, sequence

The purpose of this challenge is to find the general term of a given arithmetic or geometric sequence.

#### Explanation

The formula for an arithmetic sequence is as follows

a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>1</sub> + (n-1)d

where a<sub>1</sub> is the first term of the sequence, n is the index of the term, and d is the common difference between the terms. For a geometric sequence, the formula for the general term is

a<sub>n</sub> = a<sub>1</sub>r<sup>n-1</sup>

where r is the common ratio between the terms of the sequence.

#### Challenge

The objective of this challenge is to accept an input of a sequence of numbers, determine whether the sequence is arithmetic or geometric, and then output the formula for the general term. The rules are

- The input will be either a geometric sequence or an arithmetic sequence, nothing else
- The formula can either be returned from a function, or printed to STDOUT or an equivalent
- The input can be taken in any form that is convenient; for example, it could be an argument, taken from STDIN, or hardcoded if the language offers no other way of accepting input
- The input will always be in the format `[3, 4, 5, 6]`, with brackets surrounding comma-separated terms. The spaces separating the terms and the commas are optional. The input will always contain three or more terms.
- The shortest code in bytes wins

#### Test cases

```
Input                      Output
[-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]        -2 + 2(n-1) or an equivalent expression
[27, 9, 3, 1, 1/3]              27(1/3)^n-1 or an equivalent expression
[200, 240, 280, 320]       200 + 40(n-1) or an equivalent expression
[2, 6, 18]             2(3)^n-1 or an equivalent expression
```

#### Bonus

*-20%* 
If your answer outputs a simplified version of the formula; for example, it prints

```
6n-2
```

rather than

```
4 + 6(n-1)
```

*-30 bytes*
If your answer prints the 20th term of the sequence, in addition to the general term.

If your answer satisfies both of these conditions, the 20% is removed first, and then the 30 bytes are removed.

Comment: Near-duplicate (not quite, though): http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/37928/3808

Comment: Will the input always have four terms?

Comment: Not necessarily, I'll make that clearer in the question.

Comment: Related: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/65664/42545

Comment: [Also related](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3485/194) (but much more complicated)

Comment: Should "*The input will be either a geometric sequence or an arithmetic sequence, nothing else*" be taken to mean that the input is never both a geometric and an arithmetic sequence (i.e. a constant sequence)? What type are the input elements? The test cases imply that they should be a built-in rational type, but for languages which don't have (i.e. most of them), can they substitute e.g. a two-element array of `[numerator denominator]`?

Answer (score 1):

## 2, 38 chars / 57 bytes

```
î+(x=ì-í≔í-î?`+⟮(n-1)`⟯+(í-î):`(⦃í/î})^Ⅰ
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter2.html?eval=true&input=%5B-2%2C%200%2C%202%2C%204%2C%206%2C%208%5D&code=%C3%AE%2B%28%C3%AC-%C3%AD%E2%89%94%C3%AD-%C3%AE%3F%60%2B%E2%9F%AE%28n-1%29%60%E2%9F%AF%2B%28%C3%AD-%C3%AE%29%3A%60%28%E2%A6%83%C3%AD%2F%C3%AE%7D%29%5E%E2%85%A0)</kbd>

First answer! I'm still working on bonuses.

## Explanation

```
î+(ì-í≔í-î?`+⟮(n-1)`⟯+(í-î):`(⦃í/î})^Ⅰ // implicit: î=input1, í=input2, ì=input3
î+                                    // Prepend a1
  (ì-í≔í-î                            // Is rate of change constant from term to term?
          ?`+⟮(n-1)`⟯+(í-î)            // arithmetic mean template
                          :`(⦃í/î})^Ⅰ // geometric mean template
                                      // implicit output
```

NOTE: `⟮` and `⟯` are copy-paste blocks; anything within those blocks is stored to be called for later pasting (using `Ⅰ`).

Comment: It should be `^(n-1)`.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 75 * 0.8 - 30 = 30 bytes

```
f=Simplify[FindSequenceFunction@{If[2#2==#+#3,2#-#2,#^2/#2],##}/@{n+1,21}]&
```

Test cases:

```
f[-2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
(* {2 (-2 + n), 36} *)

f[27, 9, 3, 1, 1/3]
(* {3^(4 - n), 1/43046721} *)

f[1, 1, 1]
(* {1, 1} *)
```

In Mathematica, `FindSequenceFunction` is a very interesting function.

```
FindSequenceFunction[{1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13}, n]
(* Fibonacci[n] *)

FindSequenceFunction[{1+a, 1+a^2, 1+a^3, 1+a^4}, n]  (* symbolic! *)
(* 1 + a^n *)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 130* 0.8 - 30 = 74 bytes

Been a while since I last answer a question and this one has been sitting in my favourites for some time!

Started at **188**

`def m(t):s=str;a=t[0];b=t[1];r=b/a;q=b-a;return((s(q)+'n'+'+'*(0<a-q)+s(a-q),a+q*19),(s(b/r)+'('+s(r)+')^n-1',b*r**18))[t[2]/b==r])`

Uses school maths to determine the coeffs and sticks them together and returns the 20th term.

Sample output: `3n-1 59`, where 59 is the 20th term.

Comment: Which Python version is this? Also, it looks like you assume that the variable `t` exists prior to calling this? You must either take it as `input` or use a function (lambda).

Comment: @StewieGriffin python 3.6, its now a function that takes a list and returns the string